# Map Clarification

Tags: collection

> I have declare the collections in trigger code:

```
Set<String> markets = new Set<String>();
Map<string, Map<Date,Holiday__c>> holidays = new Map<string, Map<Date,Holiday__c>>();
for(String market: markets) {
   holidays.put(market, new Map<Date, Holiday__c>());
}
for(Holiday record: [SELECT Date__c, Country__c FROM Holiday__c WHERE Country__c = :markets]) {
   holidays.get(record.Country__c).put(record.Date__c, record);
}
```

But for this Line it is showing error: `holidays.get(record.Country__c).put(record.Date__c, record);`

`Country__c` is a Picklist type in salesforce

> **Error: Compile Error: Invalid field Country__c for SObject Holiday**

What i am doing Mistake please anyone rectify the mistake

Comment: `for(Holiday record:` this should be `for(Holiday__c record:` .

Comment: ok Thankyou@Mr.Frodo

Answer (score 2):

Try to use below code. Instead of Holiday you should use Holiday__c custom object

```
Set<String> markets = new Set<String>();
Map<string, Map<Date,Holiday__c>> holidays = new Map<string, Map<Date,Holiday__c>>();
for(String market: markets) {
   holidays.put(market, new Map<Date, Holiday__c>());
}
for(Holiday__c record: [SELECT Date__c, Country__c FROM Holiday__c WHERE Country__c = :markets]) {
   holidays.get(record.Country__c).put(record.Date__c, record);
}
```